# Load Dynamically Created Resource File: Java

Tags: java, properties-file

I am creating the bunch of properties files dynamically with dynamic name inside resource file, for this I am using following code

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/" + fileName+ ".properties");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
properties.store(fileOut, fileName);
fileOut.close();
```

**Problem:-** Every times I have to manually refresh the resource file to access dynamically created properties file. How I can resolve this issues?

Comment: why don't you create files to external path and use them from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this by storing resources files inside class path so that class loader can load the dynamically added files.

```
public static void addResourceURLIntoClassPath(URL u) throws IOException {
    URLClassLoader urlLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class<URLClassLoader> sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;
    try {
        Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(urlLoader, new Object[] { u });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Here URL is the path of src/main/resources

Comment: Thank you very much, It's working.!
I have called this method using `addResourceURLIntoClassPath(new File("/Users/pratik/Documents/Projects/RobotSampleTest/com.automation/src/test/resources").toURI().toURL());`

Answer (score 1):

Better solution to this would be using apache-commons configuration project. It offer much cleaner and tested apis. Here is the [link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_reloading.html) on how to use it.